# How do I make linear-gradient background in email?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm trying to build an email template based on https://www.muicss.com/docs/v1/example-layouts/html-email.

On top of what they offer, I'd like to have a two solid color background: color A for the top fixed height (say 200px), and color B for the rest of the content, and the table (cards) floating across the two colors, similar to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137660/how-to-create-this-material-design-background-see-image-below-with-css/45127784).

I tried different options using `linear-background`, but it doesn't show at all, the gradient starts from the bottom of the card, or the card's color becomes transparent when copied to Gmail web client (even after I inlined styles)

This is what I have for now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <!-- NOTE: external links are for testing only -->
    <style>
        body {
            width: 100% !important;
            min-width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #FFF;
        }

        .mui-body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        color: #212121;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.429;
        letter-spacing: 0.001em;
        background-color: #FFF;
        
    
        }


        .mui-container, .mui-container-fixed {
            max-width: 600px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            clear: both;
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }

        .mui-container-fixed {
            width: 600px;
        }

        .mui-panel {
            padding: 15px;
            border-radius: 0;
            background-color: #FFF;
            border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
            border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
            border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #d4d4d4;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table class="mui-body" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center>
                    <!--[if mso]><table><tr><td class="mui-container-fixed"><![endif]-->
                    <div class="mui-container">
                        <table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="mui-panel">
                                    <table id="content-wrapper" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <p>random</p>
                                                    <p>text</p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                       
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

If only email clients decided to sit down and strictly follow the RFCs... If only they would use the same html css parsing engine...

The question isn't so much HOW but rather, WHAT type of html and css most email clients **support consistently** across the board. You will find most clients just do their own thing when it comes to parsing your emails and you could end up writing many templates from scratch for the same email.

To save you some time search ***Foundation for Emails*** on Google. See direct Link below.

[Foundation for Emails | Responsive Email Templates](https://get.foundation/emails/email-templates.html)

Foundation for emails is a framework that helps you develop your own custom email templates from templates they already have. Fluid & Responsive for any device. Very clean.

In the process, you will learn which CSS and HTML tags you can use and which aren't supported. Many aren't supported.. To give you an idea, html layouts in emails are created using `<table></table>` instead of `<div></div>`. The DOCTYPE you're using is also not ideal; think early 2000's.

Example of correct doctype for all universal emails you will ever write:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Yeah I wish there is some kind of standards that all clients agree to support. Tbh, I've been working with the template for weeks without any coding background so this is going to be a long work for me. But what I want is pretty simple, so hopefully I find the solution soon enough. I'll try your doctype and mingle with it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Email clients does not support all the css properties. So in short better you use images for linear gradient.